# Additional form in Symfony Admin Generator Form

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-forms

I am currently working on a model that has tags.

For tags, I need an additional Form, but everything generated by the form generator is  wrapped inside `<form>` tag.

How can I put an additional form into my current form generated by Symfony form generator?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

make a new form class and set in

```
config:
  form:
    class: xxxxxx
```

xxxxx = the name from your new Form Class.

more info in: http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/06-Admin-Generator#chapter_06_form

Answer (score 0):

In the configure() method for your form class, you can embed additional forms.

in /lib/form/myForm.class.php:

```
    public function configure()
    {
      $other_form = new OtherForm();
      $this->embedForm('Other Form', $other_form);
    }
```